# Inclusion-Exclusion Principle Math Problem

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose a school with 120 students offers yoga and karate. If the number of students taking yoga alone is twice the number taking karate (possibly, karate and yoga), if 25 more students study neither skill than study both skills, and if 75 students take at least one skill, then how many students study yoga?

Comment: What about this is giving you trouble?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ and $B$ be the set of students taking yoga and karate respectively. We have

$$|A \setminus B|=2|B|\\|(A\cup B)^c|=|A \cap B|+25\\|A\cup B|=75$$
Also, $|(A\cup B)^c|+|A\cup B|=120.$ Therefore, $|(A\cup B)^c|=120-75=45$.
Hence, $|A\cap B|=45-25=20.$

Now $$|A|=|A \setminus B|+|A\cap B|=2|B|+20$$

Also, $$75=|A\cup B|=|A\setminus B|+|B|=3|B|.$$Therefore, $|B|=25.$ It follows that $|A|=70.$